# strange grey block on safari desktop using supersized plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari, supersized

I'm having a strange issue with safari for desktop. I checked in the rest of browsers and everything is fine. I get a grey block on the top of the viewport. I cannot target it and I ignore what could be the problem as it only happens with Safari. I also could not find any documentation regarding this issue in their website.

If you wish to see it in action use safari and check this temporal [link](http://rosasusaeta.com/cepods/design-bar.php).

I would really appreciate some help here!!

[image]

Hello everybody! I just found a way to target Safari and solve this issue. This is a temporal solution, of somebody could help me to make a better and cleaner solution I will give their answer as correct:

Answer (score 1):

I found it!

Add margin:0; to #supersized

```
#supersized {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:-999;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  margin: 0;
}
```